# Converting dates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

How can I convert one date format to another format in JavaScript?

Example:

the old format is

> YYYY/MM/DD

but I want to convert it into

> DD-MM-YYYY

Comment: so the format is done in another language and you just want javascript to convert it for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use [**jQuery UI**](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/) library's [**datepicker**](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker): use the [**parseDate**](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate) method to convert a string to a Date object, and then [**formatDate**](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) to convert the Date object to another string. Check the samples provided on the site; they include format modifiers.

Answer (score 2):

Here -

```
// Utility function to append a 0 to single-digit numbers
Date.LZ = function(x) {return(x<0||x>9?"":"0")+x};
// Full month names. Change this for local month names
Date.monthNames = new Array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');
// Month abbreviations. Change this for local month names
Date.monthAbbreviations = new Array('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec');
// Full day names. Change this for local month names
Date.dayNames = new Array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
// Day abbreviations. Change this for local month names
Date.dayAbbreviations = new Array('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat');
// Used for parsing ambiguous dates like 1/2/2000 - default to preferring 'American' format meaning Jan 2.
// Set to false to prefer 'European' format meaning Feb 1
Date.preferAmericanFormat = true;

// If the getFullYear() method is not defined, create it
if (!Date.prototype.getFullYear) { 
  Date.prototype.getFullYear = function() { var yy=this.getYear(); return (yy<1900?yy+1900:yy); } ;
} 

// Parse a string and convert it to a Date object.
// If no format is passed, try a list of common formats.
// If string cannot be parsed, return null.
// Avoids regular expressions to be more portable.
Date.parseString = function(val, format) {
  // If no format is specified, try a few common formats
  if (typeof(format)=="undefined" || format==null || format=="") {
    var generalFormats=new Array('y-M-d','MMM d, y','MMM d,y','y-MMM-d','d-MMM-y','MMM d','MMM-d','d-MMM');
    var monthFirst=new Array('M/d/y','M-d-y','M.d.y','M/d','M-d');
    var dateFirst =new Array('d/M/y','d-M-y','d.M.y','d/M','d-M');
    var checkList=new Array(generalFormats,Date.preferAmericanFormat?monthFirst:dateFirst,Date.preferAmericanFormat?dateFirst:monthFirst);
    for (var i=0; i<checkList.length; i++) {
      var l=checkList[i];
      for (var j=0; j<l.length; j++) {
        var d=Date.parseString(val,l[j]);
        if (d!=null) { 
          return d; 
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  };

  this.isInteger = function(val) {
    for (var i=0; i < val.length; i++) {
      if ("1234567890".indexOf(val.charAt(i))==-1) { 
        return false; 
      }
    }
    return true;
  };
  this.getInt = function(str,i,minlength,maxlength) {
    for (var x=maxlength; x>=minlength; x--) {
      var token=str.substring(i,i+x);
      if (token.length < minlength) { 
        return null; 
      }
      if (this.isInteger(token)) { 
        return token; 
      }
    }
  return null;
  };
  val=val+"";
  format=format+"";
  var i_val=0;
  var i_format=0;
  var c="";
  var token="";
  var token2="";
  var x,y;
  var year=new Date().getFullYear();
  var month=1;
  var date=1;
  var hh=0;
  var mm=0;
  var ss=0;
  var ampm="";
  while (i_format < format.length) {
    // Get next token from format string
    c=format.charAt(i_format);
    token="";
    while ((format.charAt(i_format)==c) && (i_format < format.length)) {
      token += format.charAt(i_format++);
    }
    // Extract contents of value based on format token
    if (token=="yyyy" || token=="yy" || token=="y") {
      if (token=="yyyy") { 
        x=4;y=4; 
      }
      if (token=="yy") { 
        x=2;y=2; 
      }
      if (token=="y") { 
        x=2;y=4; 
      }
      year=this.getInt(val,i_val,x,y);
      if (year==null) { 
        return null; 
      }
      i_val += year.length;
      if (year.length==2) {
        if (year > 70) { 
          year=1900+(year-0); 
        }
        else { 
          year=2000+(year-0); 
        }
      }
    }
    else if (token=="MMM" || token=="NNN"){
      month=0;
      var names = (token=="MMM"?(Date.monthNames.concat(Date.monthAbbreviations)):Date.monthAbbreviations);
      for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
        var month_name=names[i];
        if (val.substring(i_val,i_val+month_name.length).toLowerCase()==month_name.toLowerCase()) {
          month=(i%12)+1;
          i_val += month_name.length;
          break;
        }
      }
      if ((month < 1)||(month>12)){
        return null;
      }
    }
    else if (token=="EE"||token=="E"){
      var names = (token=="EE"?Date.dayNames:Date.dayAbbreviations);
      for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
        var day_name=names[i];
        if (val.substring(i_val,i_val+day_name.length).toLowerCase()==day_name.toLowerCase()) {
          i_val += day_name.length;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    else if (token=="MM"||token=="M") {
      month=this.getInt(val,i_val,token.length,2);
      if(month==null||(month<1)||(month>12)){
        return null;
      }
      i_val+=month.length;
    }
    else if (token=="dd"||token=="d") {
      date=this.getInt(val,i_val,token.length,2);
      if(date==null||(date<1)||(date>31)){
        return null;
      }
      i_val+=date.length;
    }
    else if (token=="hh"||token=="h") {
      hh=this.getInt(val,i_val,token.length,2);
      if(hh==null||(hh<1)||(hh>12)){
        return null;
      }
      i_val+=hh.length;
    }
    else if (token=="HH"||token=="H") {
      hh=this.getInt(val,i_val,token.length,2);
      if(hh==null||(hh<0)||(hh>23)){
        return null;
      }
      i_val+=hh.length;
    }
    else if (token=="KK"||token=="K") {
      hh=this.getInt(val,i_val,token.length,2);
      if(hh==null||(hh<0)||(hh>11)){
        return null;
      }
      i_val+=hh.length;
      hh++;
    }
    else if (token=="kk"||token=="k") {
      hh=this.getInt(val,i_val,token.length,2);
      if(hh==null||(hh<1)||(hh>24)){
        return null;
      }
      i_val+=hh.length;
      hh--;
    }
    else if (token=="mm"||token=="m") {
      mm=this.getInt(val,i_val,token.length,2);
      if(mm==null||(mm<0)||(mm>59)){
        return null;
      }
      i_val+=mm.length;
    }
    else if (token=="ss"||token=="s") {
      ss=this.getInt(val,i_val,token.length,2);
      if(ss==null||(ss<0)||(ss>59)){
        return null;
      }
      i_val+=ss.length;
    }
    else if (token=="a") {
      if (val.substring(i_val,i_val+2).toLowerCase()=="am") {
        ampm="AM";
      }
      else if (val.substring(i_val,i_val+2).toLowerCase()=="pm") {
        ampm="PM";
      }
      else {
        return null;
      }
      i_val+=2;
    }
    else {
      if (val.substring(i_val,i_val+token.length)!=token) {
        return null;
      }
      else {
        i_val+=token.length;
      }
    }
  }
  // If there are any trailing characters left in the value, it doesn't match
  if (i_val != val.length) { 
    return null; 
  }
  // Is date valid for month?
  if (month==2) {
    // Check for leap year
    if ( ( (year%4==0)&&(year%100 != 0) ) || (year%400==0) ) { // leap year
      if (date > 29){ 
        return null; 
      }
    }
    else { 
      if (date > 28) { 
        return null; 
      } 
    }
  }
  if ((month==4)||(month==6)||(month==9)||(month==11)) {
    if (date > 30) { 
      return null; 
    }
  }
  // Correct hours value
  if (hh<12 && ampm=="PM") {
    hh=hh-0+12; 
  }
  else if (hh>11 && ampm=="AM") { 
    hh-=12; 
  }
  return new Date(year,month-1,date,hh,mm,ss);
};

// Check if a date string is valid
Date.isValid = function(val,format) {
  return (Date.parseString(val,format) != null);
};

// Check if a date object is before another date object
Date.prototype.isBefore = function(date2) {
  if (date2==null) { 
    return false; 
  }
  return (this.getTime()<date2.getTime());
};

// Check if a date object is after another date object
Date.prototype.isAfter = function(date2) {
  if (date2==null) { 
    return false; 
  }
  return (this.getTime()>date2.getTime());
};

// Check if two date objects have equal dates and times
Date.prototype.equals = function(date2) {
  if (date2==null) { 
    return false; 
  }
  return (this.getTime()==date2.getTime());
};

// Check if two date objects have equal dates, disregarding times
Date.prototype.equalsIgnoreTime = function(date2) {
  if (date2==null) { 
    return false; 
  }
  var d1 = new Date(this.getTime()).clearTime();
  var d2 = new Date(date2.getTime()).clearTime();
  return (d1.getTime()==d2.getTime());
};

// Format a date into a string using a given format string
Date.prototype.format = function(format) {
  format=format+"";
  var result="";
  var i_format=0;
  var c="";
  var token="";
  var y=this.getYear()+"";
  var M=this.getMonth()+1;
  var d=this.getDate();
  var E=this.getDay();
  var H=this.getHours();
  var m=this.getMinutes();
  var s=this.getSeconds();
  var yyyy,yy,MMM,MM,dd,hh,h,mm,ss,ampm,HH,H,KK,K,kk,k;
  // Convert real date parts into formatted versions
  var value=new Object();
  if (y.length < 4) {
    y=""+(+y+1900);
  }
  value["y"]=""+y;
  value["yyyy"]=y;
  value["yy"]=y.substring(2,4);
  value["M"]=M;
  value["MM"]=Date.LZ(M);
  value["MMM"]=Date.monthNames[M-1];
  value["NNN"]=Date.monthAbbreviations[M-1];
  value["d"]=d;
  value["dd"]=Date.LZ(d);
  value["E"]=Date.dayAbbreviations[E];
  value["EE"]=Date.dayNames[E];
  value["H"]=H;
  value["HH"]=Date.LZ(H);
  if (H==0){
    value["h"]=12;
  }
  else if (H>12){
    value["h"]=H-12;
  }
  else {
    value["h"]=H;
  }
  value["hh"]=Date.LZ(value["h"]);
  value["K"]=value["h"]-1;
  value["k"]=value["H"]+1;
  value["KK"]=Date.LZ(value["K"]);
  value["kk"]=Date.LZ(value["k"]);
  if (H > 11) { 
    value["a"]="PM"; 
  }
  else { 
    value["a"]="AM"; 
  }
  value["m"]=m;
  value["mm"]=Date.LZ(m);
  value["s"]=s;
  value["ss"]=Date.LZ(s);
  while (i_format < format.length) {
    c=format.charAt(i_format);
    token="";
    while ((format.charAt(i_format)==c) && (i_format < format.length)) {
      token += format.charAt(i_format++);
    }
    if (typeof(value[token])!="undefined") { 
      result=result + value[token]; 
    }
    else { 
      result=result + token; 
    }
  }
  return result;
};

// Get the full name of the day for a date
Date.prototype.getDayName = function() { 
  return Date.dayNames[this.getDay()];
};

// Get the abbreviation of the day for a date
Date.prototype.getDayAbbreviation = function() { 
  return Date.dayAbbreviations[this.getDay()];
};

// Get the full name of the month for a date
Date.prototype.getMonthName = function() {
  return Date.monthNames[this.getMonth()];
};

// Get the abbreviation of the month for a date
Date.prototype.getMonthAbbreviation = function() { 
  return Date.monthAbbreviations[this.getMonth()];
};

// Clear all time information in a date object
Date.prototype.clearTime = function() {
  this.setHours(0); 
  this.setMinutes(0);
  this.setSeconds(0); 
  this.setMilliseconds(0);
  return this;
};

// Add an amount of time to a date. Negative numbers can be passed to subtract time.
Date.prototype.add = function(interval, number) {
  if (typeof(interval)=="undefined" || interval==null || typeof(number)=="undefined" || number==null) { 
    return this; 
  }
  number = +number;
  if (interval=='y') { // year
    this.setFullYear(this.getFullYear()+number);
  }
  else if (interval=='M') { // Month
    this.setMonth(this.getMonth()+number);
  }
  else if (interval=='d') { // Day
    this.setDate(this.getDate()+number);
  }
  else if (interval=='w') { // Weekday
    var step = (number>0)?1:-1;
    while (number!=0) {
      this.add('d',step);
      while(this.getDay()==0 || this.getDay()==6) { 
        this.add('d',step);
      }
      number -= step;
    }
  }
  else if (interval=='h') { // Hour
    this.setHours(this.getHours() + number);
  }
  else if (interval=='m') { // Minute
    this.setMinutes(this.getMinutes() + number);
  }
  else if (interval=='s') { // Second
    this.setSeconds(this.getSeconds() + number);
  }
  return this;
};
```

Copy this to a .js file, and include it in your page.

Then you can use the format() method on the Date object.

You can also find another library [here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format).

Comment: Who wrote it & owns the copy right, and under what license is it available?

Answer (score 2):

My date extensions will do that well - they also parses data formats and does a lot of date math/compares as well:

[DP_DateExtensions Library](http://www.depressedpress.com/Content/Development/JavaScript/Extensions/DP_DateExtensions/Index.cfm)

Not sure if it'll help, but I've found it invaluable in several projects.  The date functions are (mostly) based on CFML (if that matters).

I'm not saying that they're better than the other options given - but I am proud of them and it never (well... almost never) hurts to be spoilt for choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use jQuery (and I can't think why, but just in case), I have created a patch for the Javascript Date object which will allow you to both parse dates from strings in different formats and convert dates to strings in different formats.

You can see more info on [Javascript Date Formatter](http://miljenkobarbir.com/javascript-date-formatter/) article on my blog.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is very late but I think following solution is simple and effective for this question. This works for me always.

Here you go :

function dateToYMD(date) {
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    return ''+ (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d) + '-' + (m<=9 ? '0' + m : m) + '-' + y ;
}