# Converting Java date string to JavaScript date

Tags: java, javascript

Is there any JavaScript library that takes Java's `SimpleDateFormat` pattern and parses a date/time string into a `Date` object?

For example, given `"2010-12-20"` and `"yyyy-MM-dd"`, the function would parse `"2010-12-20"` and return a JavaScript `Date`.

I noticed that jQuery UI's Date Picker can format and parse a date string, but it doesn't work with a time string.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you want: http://www.timdown.co.uk/code/simpledateformat.php

Answer (score 1):

I would try the Datejs library: http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: The format strings used by datejs (see http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers) are not compatible with SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Are you saying that Datejs's parseExact function called like this 'var myDate = Date.parseExact("2010-12-10", "yyyy-MM-dd");' doesn't work? It seems to me it covers the OP's example and may in fact cover a lot more that he needs. Maybe I should have been a little forthcoming in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not the only looking for it. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007732/java-date-format-to-javascript-date-format) that has similar content. In the end, the author had to role his/her own but there are some good suggestions in there that might be of benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Google's GWT project has a class to do this.
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html
Probably no small job to get that into a standalone javascript, though.